# How to handle errors in GRequests?

Tags: python, python-requests, grequests

I have this code

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import grequests

urls = [
'http://google.com',
'http://doesnotexists.tld'
]


def do_something(response, **kwargs):
        print response.text

async_list = []

for u in urls:
    action_item = grequests.get(u, timeout=10, hooks = {'response' : do_something})
    async_list.append(action_item)

grequests.map(async_list,size=10)
```

How do I handle errors without getting usual Python error messages?
For example for domain which does not exists it prints out "not found".

Comment: You could use try and except like described here https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html

Comment: Still does not work


`try:
grequests.map(async_list,size=10)
except ConnectionError as e:
    print e`

Comment: Um. what does not work? If you don't what the output then dont print it! (replace `print e` with  `pass`)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that `grequests` installed from pypi (with pip) doesn't include exception handling. But the version from github has implemented that feature:

```
def map(requests, stream=False, size=None, exception_handler=None)
```

So you should clone grequests or download grequests.py from github and use that version. You can directly install that version with pip:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/kennethreitz/grequests.git
```

If you're looking for exception handling examples you could have a look at the test.py in the repository. https://github.com/kennethreitz/grequests/blob/master/tests.py

Answer (score 1):

This has been fixed with the latest release of grequests - https://github.com/kennethreitz/grequests